# Fix-A-Thred... Helicoils?

Tags: stripped-thread, thread, tap

So I bought the m10x1.5 fix a thred kit from advance auto parts today to fix a stripped hole in the subframe that my upper control arm goes into. These bolts are crucial as they’re the only things holding the control arm to the frame (and thus the knuckle). I bought the tap because I’m using grade 10.9 bolts that are aftermarket because OEM ones weren’t salvageable (also because the nut at the back of the subframe broke off and I don’t want to cut it open). The fix a thred kit comes with a handle, tap, and helicoils. My questions are: 
-if I drill the holes out with the recommended 13/32 bit and then run the tap through, would that be enough to strongly hold the new bolts?
-do I need to install the helicoils? What purpose do they serve(id really like to just put the bolt into the subframe without these)?
-if I need to put the helicoils in, are they strong and reliable enough (like the grade 10.9 bolt) to hold up to the stresses of the suspension?

Thank you for any answers, I want to do this job right with a permanent fix and not a temporary patch up!

Comment: How thick is the metal that you are tapping?  Are you saying that there was a nut behind that sheet steel that you are now attempting to tap without the nut?

Comment: Yes, it’s about 30mm thick

Comment: There was a nut that broke off and I cut the bolt connected to it so the bolt is nonexistent now

Comment: Are you able to provide a photo, it is hard to imagine the subframe being 30mm thick steel and then having a nut on the back of it.

Comment: That does sound like it will be hollow ie it is two pressings welded together : that is how many subframes are made...

Comment: Ok will have pics in about 5 hours, in school atm

Comment: As @SolarMike says it is more than likely a hollow box.  It may well have a tube welded through it where the bolt goes through which makes it look solid.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd be trusting a suspension component to a fix-a-thread/helicoil  "fix". These are crucial components which see a lot of stress. While thread replacement works really well for static loads (like head bolts or other engine based threads), I'm not sure how it's going to hold for a dynamic load which suspension parts incur. Just my humble opinion.

Comment: What should I use then? I can’t think of another way to attach the arm

Comment: @sjfklsdafjks did you read about the plate with nut I suggested in my answer?

Comment: I did but the angle of the whole area is an issue in itself, I’ll have pics in 30 mins, basically I don’t know where to cut to even try access the back of the bolt, so I wasn’t considering even cutting the frame yet until I could maybe find some place to cut it... any suggestions on how to know where to cut?

Comment: @SolarMike and Paul and howie ||| https://imgur.com/a/hlbU7

Comment: The one with my finger on that pick looking tool is about how much material there is, and the tap is there for reference (m10x1.5)

Comment: Is the subframe made out of steel, or is it aluminium?

Comment: Steel, I just checked it

Comment: It is difficult to suggest anything here, just in case it makes the car unsafe. There does look like there is plenty of material to tap into, but you would have thought they wouldn't have needed the nut if that was the case.

Comment: I’m just going to drill the hole to tap an m10 bolt and helicoil it with loctite, then do a few welds around that bar piece going through the bushing to hold it to the subframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the thickness of the metal you are tapping is greater than 1.5 times the bolt diameter then it **should** be ok, but this also depends on the metal and its grade. If not then all it will do under load is to strip the threads and possibly be the cause of an accident.

You may need to consider welding a nut to a plate and then having that plate with nut welded into position to provide sufficient fixing.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: only one of the bolt holes was thick enough to tap, so I tapped and helicoiled it with success! The other hole was like 10mm thick and wasn’t viable for tapping, so I ended up cutting a little flap(3 sided square) in the bottom of the subframe and peeling it back just enough to fit a nut and pliers through so I could get that nut back in. Thank you to all who replied, and good luck anyone with the same issues!!!!

P.S make sure to use a LOT of oil/tapping fluid(wd40 works) when tapping and be patient as to not to break the tap(I didn’t know if the tap was useable for steel or not), I used one from autozone and wd40/a little (2hrs) of patience goes a long way!!!!

Comment: Sounds like a good job, well done and hope you get plenty of use out of it.